# Can I get emergency appointment from US because I have an appointment in a consulate in US?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I need a visa to enter US.

Waiting time is like 5 months for US B1/2 visa in where I reside.

If I have a permanent residency visa appointment at a consulate in US, can US give me an emergency appointment so I don't wait for 5 months?

Comment: What it is the emergency? For emergency appointments you need an emergency. Just "don't have to wait" is not an emergency

Comment: Why not? They give emergency appointments to students

Comment: I’m confused. If you’re not in the US, why did you make an appointment for a consulate in the US? And what country’s consulate is it?

Comment: That doesn’t answer my questions. What consulate is it? Why didn’t you make an appointment at the consulate in the country you’re in?

Comment: Wait, did you mean to say that it’s a US consulate, rather than some consulate  “in the US”?

Comment: How can you apply for a *non immigrant* visa with a stated aim of applying for an *immigrant* status once in the US? The two seem incompatible to me

Comment: Permanent residency visas are issued by consulates of this country are issued ONLY in a couple of countries in the world. US is one of those countries and my country isn't one of them.

Comment: This question is incredibly unclear. Can you state exactly what you're trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: Goal: Get permanent residency visa from a consulate in the US. To enter US, I need a visa. ]]]]] See my previous comment

Comment: @user131214 What consulate are you wanting to visit, and what country are you currently in?

Comment: @user131214 So you want an answer to your vague question, but are refusing to provide additional information requested by potential answerers?  You're less likely to receive a satisfactory answer this way.

Comment: @user131214, the most important rules here is 'be nice'.  You are not nice to people who try to help you. The information they ask is needed to answer your question, as your question lacked a lot of details. If there are not enough details the question will get closed and may not get an answer at all.

Comment: @user131214 On what basis do you qualify to apply for PR in the US? It sounds like you think you can enter as a visitor and then apply for PR, which is unlikely unless your situation fits one of these categories https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-eligibility-categories or you qualify via another means that you need to explain if you hope to get an answer.  Otherwise your question will almost certainly be closed

Comment: @user131214 No, **you** are not reading all the comments asking for more details in order to give an answer. English is my native language, I *have* read your post and I can assure you that as the question is currently worded it makes *zero* sense (as evidenced by the 4 ‘close’ votes it has attracted so far) and your situation does not sound like an *emergency*

Comment: @user131214 I would edit your question to make it clear what you're asking, because as of now it is *not* clear (even though I *think* I managed to understand from reading all of your comments). But being called a "weirdo" does not make me want to do nice things for you, sorry.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - there are no US consulates inside the USA. So you don't need a B visa to enter the USA in order to apply for permanent residency - that's not how the process works.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you currently live in a country we'll call A and want to apply for permanent residence in a country we'll call B. Country B has no embassy in A, or it doesn't issue permanent residence visas or something, so you wish to travel to the US to make your application. But Country A nationals can not enter the US without a visa and you want to expedite your US visa application.

Assuming this understanding is correct, the answer is **no, this is not likely to be an emergency as the US defines it.**

The exact definition of "emergency" appears to vary by visa issuing post, so you should check the US embassy web page in the country you live, but for example in Mexico, [the criteria are](https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-mx/niv/information/faqs#need_earlier_appt):

> - An immediate relative's death, grave illness or life threatening accident taking place in the United States.
> - Urgent medical treatment for the applicant or their minor child.
> - An applicant for a student or exchange visitor (F/M/J) visa whose I-20 or DS-2019 has a start date that is earlier than the first available visa appointment.
> - An unexpected need to travel to the United States for urgent business purposes that is occurring within 10 days after the first available visa appointment.
> - An unexpected visit that is of significant cultural, political, journalistic, sporting or economic importance that is occurring within 10 days after the first available visa appointment.

If you are willing to disclose the identities of countries A and B, people here may be able to help you think of other ways to solve your problem, but as written, your question is too vague for any more answer than this.